# Azure load test task on a pipeline, test uses CSV file. How can I set the test in the pipeline with the CSV file

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines

just started working on some Jmeter tests.

The project already has 5 Jmeter tests , they are created with Apache and then imported in the project solution in Visual Studio and create a YAML file for each.
The change set is checked in a dev branch.

Then at night it is run on a pipeline where there is a Azure load test defined for each test.

I have a new test that uses a csv file in order to use a different cookie for each user(thread).
Imported the test in visual studio and created the YAML file for it.
Will check in the changes to dev branch.

But I don't know how to set up the test in the pipeline together with the CSV file.

Have not tried anything because when we define a Azure load test task in the pipeline, there is no option to also have a data file with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [Azure Load Testing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/load-testing) the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-create-and-run-load-test-with-jmeter-script?tabs=portal#create-a-load-test) states:

> You can upload additional JMeter configuration files or other files that you reference in the JMX file. **For example, if your test script uses CSV data sets, you can upload the corresponding .csv file(s)**. See also [how to read data from a CSV file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-read-csv-data?tabs=portal). For files other than JMeter scripts and user properties, if the size of the file is greater than 50 MB, zip the file. The size of the zip file should be below 50 MB. Azure Load Testing automatically unzips the file during the test run. Only five zip artifacts are allowed with a maximum of 1000 files in each zip and an uncompressed total size of 1 GB.

More information on JMeter tests parameterization with CSV files: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: Found a way, can add it from the resource group

Comment: Now the question is do I also have to specify it in the YAML...the CSV file

Comment: via [`configurationFiles`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/load-testing/how-to-read-csv-data.md#tab/pipelines+github) attribute